# How to generate public key for Okamoto Uchiyama Cryptosystem?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, number-theory

I am implementing Okamoto Uchiyama Cryptosystem in Java. The algorithm is [here](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FOkamoto%25E2%2580%2593Uchiyama_cryptosystem&ei=1xWpVL3TA4eJuASDwYHYCQ&usg=AFQjCNEcQPv3w0I5iZR_D2D2j67MOSJHsg&sig2=1d33QbI8iajs18W7mwc7Kw)

For public key, value of a parameter *h* is calculated as,

```
h = g^n mod n
```

where,

*g* is primitive root of prime *p* (340 bits)

```
n = p^2 * q (1024bits)
```

I have used BigInteger type for *g*, *h* and *n*. When I run the code, it is not terminating. Here is the code. Please suggest me how to calculate *h*.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Random;

public class KeyPairGeneration {

    PrimeGenerator PrimeGeneratorObject = new PrimeGenerator();
    BigInteger PrivateFields[] = new BigInteger[2];
    BigInteger PublicFields[] = new BigInteger[4];
    BigInteger ONE = new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger DECREMENT = new BigInteger("-1");

    /**
     * Generate Private Key with two large primes
     */
    public BigInteger[] PrivateKeyGenerator() {
        PrivateFields[0] = PrimeGeneratorObject.RandomPrime();      // p
        PrivateFields[1] = PrimeGeneratorObject.RandomPrime();      // q

        if(PrivateFields[0] != PrivateFields[1])
            return PrivateFields;
        else
            return PrivateKeyGenerator();
    }

    /**
     * Generate Public Key from Private Key
     */
    public BigInteger[] PublicKeyGenerator() {

        PublicFields[0] = PrivateFields[0].multiply(PrivateFields[0]).multiply(PrivateFields[1]);   // n = p*p*q

        BigInteger g = new BigInteger("1");
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        for (int idx = 1; idx <= PrivateFields[0].intValue(); ++idx){
          int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
          if (primitiveRoot(randomInt, PrivateFields[0].intValue())) {
              BigInteger primitiveRoot = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(randomInt));

              PublicFields[1] = g.multiply(primitiveRoot);                                          // g = primitive root of P
              break;
          }
        }

        int randomizationValue = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
        PublicFields[2] = BigInteger.valueOf(randomizationValue);                                   // r < n

        PublicFields[3] = PublicFields[1].modPow(PublicFields[0],PublicFields[0]);                  // h = g^n mod n

        return PublicFields;
    }

     public static boolean primitiveRoot(int a, int p) {
            int val = a, i;
            // Calculate each modular exponent a^2, a^3... mod p.
            for (i=2; i<p; i++) {
                val = val*a%p;
                if (val == 1)
                    break;
            }
            // If the exponent is p-1, it's a primitive root!
                return (i == p-1);
        }

}
```

Comment: You should really try and keep to Java code practices especially with regards to naming of your identifiers. See the old [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) that everybody still uses.

Comment: I'll follow the naming conventions Maarten Bodewes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p` doesn't fit into an int, so `PrivateFields[0].intValue()` must be wrong. Your `primitiveRoot` algorithm has to take `BigInteger` and not `int`.